# Trigger Teamcity build on successful Git merge

Tags: regex, git, teamcity

We want our Teamcity server to do an automatic build whenever someone merges something back to the master branch.

To do this we have created a new VCS Trigger and checked the `Trigger a build on each check-in`-option. We have disabled the `Quiet period mode` and added a regular expression for the trigger rule.
Checking out the [Java regex documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) I've created the following regex:
`^Merge branch '[a-zA-Z0-9\p{Punct}]+' into 'master'$` which translates to the following in the **Trigger rules** textblock: `+:comment=^Merge branch '[a-zA-Z0-9\p{Punct}]+' into 'master'$` or `+:comment=^Merge branch '[a-zA-Z0-9\p{Punct}]+' into 'master'$:**` (I haven't got the slightest idea what `:**` should do, but the [TC documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+VCS+Triggers) uses this sometimes)

This should match something like:

> Merge branch 'test' into 'master'

or

> Merge branch 'feature-cs-200' into 'master'

However, the builds are never triggered. Apparently the regex doesn't match the correct pattern.

Any ideas?

**Finished...**
Apparently Teamcity has decided the `+:comment=^Merge branch '[a-zA-Z0-9\p{Punct}]+' into 'master'$` regex is fine now and triggers the builds whenever a commit message matches the examples. Perhaps there was some caching or something else which caused the trigger not to fire.

Comment: why not just trigger on a commit to master? The merge will create a commit...

Comment: The reason we want this is because Teamcity will trigger 2 (or more) builds this way, one for the 'merge person' and one for the authors of the branch to be merged (because of the option: `Include several check-ins in a build if they are from the same committer`). This isn't a big problem, but it causes some overhead. Therefore we decided, for now, only builds are triggered if they are merged in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to  trigger your builds only on commits that contain the word **"merge into"**. If someone does a `fast-forward` merge, the commit messages won't record a merge message. They will instead record a list of commits.  You will never get a list of trigger.

Anyways, if you still want it to run only on merges to master, you can setup a VCS trigger on master(only) and run a teamcity target whenever the message is `+:comment=into master:**`

If nothing works, you can just try matching the regex `'+:comment=Merge branch .*` into master:**'

Comment: Biswajit, I am trying to do the same but with the difference that I am using bitbucket. The merge comment for bitbucket is a little different. It is like this
```Merged in feature/my-lovely-awesome-branch```
So based on your answer, after modifying a little, I created a trigger rule to likes of ```+:comment=Merged in feature*```. Alas! It does not trigger the build but remains in pending. Am I missing anything? Is it different for bitbucekt than what I am doing? Thank you in advance.